# deferencing pointer to incomplete type on my custom list

Tags: c, pointers

I'm writing a custom list with some operations on it but i'm having trouble with the "deferencing pointer to incomplete type error"
here are the struct definitions:

```
typedef struct TIME_NODE {
    int timeout;
    int seq_number;
    struct time_node* next;
} time_node;

typedef struct TIMEOUT_LIST {
    struct time_node* head;
} timeout_list;
```

And here is one of the functions

```
void insert(timeout_list *l, int sequence_number, int timeout)
{
    int c=0;
    struct time_node* temp;
    temp = l->head;
    if(temp==NULL)
    {
        add(sequence_number, timeout);
    }
    else
    {
        while(temp!=NULL)
        {
            if(temp->timeout < timeout) {
                c++;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        if(c==0)
            add(sequence_number, timeout);
        else if(c<count())
            add_after(sequence_number, timeout, ++c);
        else
            append(sequence_number, timeout);
    }
}
```

Why can't I deference temp?

Comment: Thanks guys, solved the problem and understood what caused it.

Comment: I am glad, you can accept the answer that worked better for you.

Comment: Note: you can omit `struct TIMEOUT_LIST` and most of the {add,add_after,append} logic by using a pointer to pointer to `struct THE_NODE` as function argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong

```
struct time_node* temp;
```

it should be

```
struct TIME_NODE* temp;
```

but since you have `typedef`ed it, then this should be enough

```
time_node* temp;
```

and you should fix it in the `struct TIMEOUT_LIST` too.

If you want either syntaxes to work then you have to use the same name for the struct and for the `typedef` like this

```
typedef struct time_node {
    int timeout;
    int seq_number;
    struct time_node* next;
} time_node;
```

and you can even do it this way

```
typedef struct time_node time_node;
struct time_node {
    int timeout;
    int seq_number;
    time_node* next;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct TIME_NODE {
    int timeout;
    int seq_number;
    struct time_node* next;
} time_node;
```

That will create a struct type called `TIME_NODE` (which can be declared using `struct TIME_NODE`, and then typedefs it to `time_node`.

You either need to declare the variable using the type `struct TIME_NODE*`, or `time_node*`.